# Why am I getting a 'No module named OpenAI' Import error?

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory, openai-gym, universe

so I was trying to make a bot to train on one of the environment of [Universe](https://blog.openai.com/universe/) and on running it, I am receiving the error (`ImportError: No module named universe`). Help me understand what this is and how I can fix it.

My code -

```
import gym
import universe
env = gym.make('HandManipulateEgg-v0')
observation_n = env.reset()

while True:
    action_n = [[('KeyEvent', 'ArrowUp', True)] for ob in observation_n]
    observation_n, reward_n, done_n, env.step(action_n)
    env.render ()
```

My system details -
[Sayon's System Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbU5m.jpg)

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: No module named `universe`, or no module named `OpenAI`?

Comment: did you install the universe package with pip or conda or sth of that sort? https://pypi.org/project/universe/
Or do you mean another package?

Comment: @dhae Yeah I did it with pip.

Comment: @9769953 no module named universe.

Comment: You'll want to [edit] your question title then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Universe appears to have migrated: https://github.com/openai/universe, per the repo you should use `retro`.

Note that the docs indicate that you can't simply `pip` this package and make it work. Specifically: ["Building Gym Retro requires at least either gcc 5 or clang 3.4."](https://github.com/openai/retro#extra-prerequesites)

There are additional rendering and ROM integration instructions in the docs as well. Overall, this points to a setup process that might be considerably more involved than you seem to be expecting. Moreover, Windows 7 may very well be incapable of meeting the system requirements for this package.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Am checking it out to see what's wrong.

Comment: You're welcome! If the response addresses your original question, please mark it as answered @SayonBhattacharya